# What is the reason the Async function that I have below is returning Promise { <pending> } instead of returning the proper value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When I `console.log()` paymentsResults and pendingResults from the code below, I can see the data being logged properly. However, right at the last moment when I am trying to return payments and pending I see the results as `Promise { <pending> }` in my backend. What is the reason and how can I fix the issue here?

```
const query = await pool.query(q);

const payments = query.rows.filter(o => getCategory(o) === "payment");
const pending = query.rows.filter(o => getCategory(o) === "pending");
const inactive = query.rows.filter(o => getCategory(o) === "inactive");

const paymentsResults = payments.map(async order => {

    const A = ({
        date: getDate(order),
        item: await getItem(order),
        total: getTotal(order),
        purchaser: getPurchaser(order),
        email: getEmail(order),
        paymentMethod: getPaidUsing(order),
        status: getStatus(order)
    });
    return A;
});



const pendingResults = pending.map(async order => {

    const B = {
        date: getDate(order),
        item: await getItem(order),
        total: getTotal(order),
        purchaser: getPurchaser(order),
        email: getEmail(order),
        status: getStatus(order)
    };

    return B;
});


return {
    payments: paymentsResults,
    pending: pendingResults,
    inactive: inactive
};
};
```

Comment: Probably because you can't `await` inside a synchronous Array method (`.map()`, `.forEach()`, `.filter()`, etc). You have to use a `for` loop if you want to await.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @JeremyThille Do you know how to write the `.map` above as a `for` loop instead?

Comment: Of course, it's basically the same thing. Have a look at [for...of loop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const paymentsResults = await Promise.all(payments.map(async order => {
    const A = {
        date: getDate(order),
        item: await getItem(order),
        total: getTotal(order),
        purchaser: getPurchaser(order),
        email: getEmail(order),
        paymentMethod: getPaidUsing(order),
        status: getStatus(order)
    };

    return A;
}));


const pendingResults = await Promise.all(pending.map(async order => {
    const B = {
        date: getDate(order),
        item: await getItem(order),
        total: getTotal(order),
        purchaser: getPurchaser(order),
        email: getEmail(order),
        status: getStatus(order)
    };

    return B;
}));
```

- array of Promise should be resolved by `Promise.all` before using.
- async function **always** returns promise.